# Como somar dois itens de um inteiro? (python, básico)

Tags: python, inteiros

Gente, minha atividade passa o número do cpf, e formata ele com o modelo normal xxx.xxx.xxx-xx, porém tenho que pegar os últimos 2 números e somar, mas quando estou tentando fazer isso separando os elementos por índice, eles não se somam, apenas ficam lado à lado. ALguém pode me ajudar em como fazer corretamente?

'''

```
cpf_r = input("CPF: ")
cpf_s = input("CPF: ")
cpf_t = input("CPF: ")
if len(cpf_r) <11:
    cpf_r = cpf.zfill(11)
cpf1 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_r[:3], cpf_r[3:6], cpf_r[6:9], cpf_r[9:])
if len(cpf_s) <11:
    cpf_s = cpf.zfill(11)
cpf2 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_s[:3], cpf_s[3:6], cpf_s[6:9], cpf_s[9:])
if len(cpf_t) <11:
    cpf_t = cpf.zfill(11)
cpf3 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_t[:3], cpf_t[3:6], cpf_t[6:9], cpf_t[9:])

a = cpf_r[9]
b = cpf_s[9] 
c = cpf_t[9] 

a1 = cpf_r[10]
b1 = cpf_s[10]
c1 = cpf_t[10]

somacpf1 = a + a1
somacpf2 = b + b1
somacpf3 = c + c1

print(cpf1)
print(somacpf1)
print(cpf2)
print(somacpf2)
print(cpf3)
print(somacpf3)
```

'''

[Era para estar rodando assim:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlWnv.png)

[MAs está rodando assim:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVExC.png)

Comment: O CPF é uma string, e ao pegar índices específicos, o resultado também é uma string (mesmo que seja um dígito, ainda sim será um caractere e não o valor numérico), então vc está na verdade concatenando strings. Para somar, primeiro tem que converter para número, algo como `a = int(cpf_r[9])` (faça o mesmo para os demais)

Answer (score -2):

Como @hkotsubo notou, você precisa definir as variáveis do fim do código como números inteiros (utilizando a função `int()`).

Além disso, as expressões `cpf_r = cpf.zfill(11)` estão erradas, falta o `_r` após `cpf` no lado direito da equação.

```
cpf_r = input("CPF: ")
cpf_s = input("CPF: ")
cpf_t = input("CPF: ")
if len(cpf_r) <11:
    cpf_r = cpf_r.zfill(11)
cpf1 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_r[:3], cpf_r[3:6], cpf_r[6:9], cpf_r[9:])
if len(cpf_s) <11:
    cpf_s = cpf_s.zfill(11)
cpf2 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_s[:3], cpf_s[3:6], cpf_s[6:9], cpf_s[9:])
if len(cpf_t) <11:
    cpf_t = cpf_t.zfill(11)
cpf3 = '{}.{}.{}-{}'.format(cpf_t[:3], cpf_t[3:6], cpf_t[6:9], cpf_t[9:])

a = int(cpf_r[9])
b = int(cpf_s[9])
c = int(cpf_t[9])

a1 = int(cpf_r[10])
b1 = int(cpf_s[10])
c1 = int(cpf_t[10])

somacpf1 = a + a1
somacpf2 = b + b1
somacpf3 = c + c1

print(cpf1)
print(somacpf1)
print(cpf2)
print(somacpf2)
print(cpf3)
print(somacpf3)
```

Resultado:

```
CPF: 11111111111
CPF: 22222222222
CPF: 33333333333
111.111.111-11
2
222.222.222-22
4
333.333.333-33
6
```